# Access App delegate from Objective C Project in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

We have an Objective C Project which is about to get some new features. These new features will be implemented in Swift. So far we have it all working with Swift and Objective C side by side and most of the things are quite pleasant to implement.

One thing I currently did not manage to accomplish is to access the (objc) app delegate from within swift, especially it's methods and the managed object context.

I tried

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate! as UIApplicationDelegate
```

without any success.

How do I access the application delegate written in Objective C from my swift code and use it's methods as well as the managed object context?

Comment: you shouldn't really have the core data stack in the app delegate...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use your appdelegate class name instead of  UIApplicationDelegate

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate! as <<Your Appdelegate Class>>
```

and also import that appdelegate in Bridging-Header file. "Bridging-Header" is used for both side bridge connection

Comment: The app delegate class (<<Your Appdelegate Class>>) seems to be unknown, since it's referred as unknown type if I do that

Comment: "Bridging-Header" is used for both side bridge connection, so import that appdelegate in  Bridging-Header file..

Comment: Importing the MyAppDelegate in the briding header breaks my Obj-C code completely. Tons of compiler errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

`let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate`

Answer (score 1):

let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

Comment: In that case "AppDelegate" seems to be an unknown type

Comment: I use as! AppDelegate(It should be your appdelegate class name.).